# Loop through a 2D array to get second column values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var linkArray = [
['boothsizeDiv_link', false],
['furnishingsprovidedDiv_link', false],
['electricalDiv_link', false],
['rentalfurnishingsDiv_link', false],
['gesgraphicsDiv_link', false],
['geslaborDiv_link', false],
['contractorDiv_link', false],
['carpetingDiv_link', false],
['boothlightingDiv_link', false],
['javitsDiv_link', false],
['boothsealDiv_link', false],
['mannequinsDiv_link', false],
['calcDiv_link', false]
];
```

How can i loop through this array to get all 'false' values from that array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a loop

```
for (var i=0;i<linkArray.length;i++)
{
     document.write(linkArray[i][1] + "<br>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of boolean values, the you can use this:

```
var falseValues = [];//this will be your list of false values

for(var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++){
    var link = linkArray[i];
    //test the value at array index 1 (i.e. the boolean part)
    if(!link[1]){
       falseValues.push(link[1]);//add the false to the list
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `for ... in` with regular arrays.

Comment: It sometimes breaks and is thus considered bad style. You can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays for example.

Comment: @musefan have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the variable name, the string values and the structure of your array, it might be a better approach to use object instead of array:

```
var linkObject = {
 boothsizeDiv_link: false,
 furnishingsprovidedDiv_link: false,
 electricalDiv_link: false,
 rentalfurnishingsDiv_link: false,
 gesgraphicsDiv_link: false,
 geslaborDiv_link: false,
 contractorDiv_link: false,
 carpetingDiv_link: false,
 boothlightingDiv_link: false,
 javitsDiv_link: false,
 boothsealDiv_link: false,
 mannequinsDiv_link: false,
 calcDiv_link: false
};
```

Now you can get the array of the boolean values like this:

```
var ret = [];
for (var propertyName in linkObject) {
    ret.push(linkObject[propertyName]);
}
```

But you can also get to a specific value like this:

```
linkObject['boothsizeDiv_link']
```

which yields `false`.